# Selling custom electronic projects online in the uk

Tags: united-kingdom, internet, licensing, regulations

(Sorry if I am posting in the wrong forum) I am wanting to have a go at selling some of my projects (mostly lighting: epoxy, led strips) after doing a search, it sounds like there are a lot of regulations about this sort of stuff. I have also read about CE which it sounds like I would need in order to sell online (I am looking at eBay), the product would use an led strip that most likely already comes with a CE mark. So I am here to ask if that would allow me to sell this lighting product straight to eBay without problems occurring with regulations? If there are problems with regulations would it be an idea to think about selling it as individual parts that the end user builds?

Answer (score 1):

If you are selling "low voltage" (meaning [under 1000 volts](http://www.ce-marking.org/directive-7323eec-low-voltage.html)) equipment across an EU border then it [requires CE marking](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/ce-marking#products-that-need-ce-marking). It sounds like your products qualify.

If you merely resell equipment that someone else has produced then you can rely on the CE marking of that equipment, but if you are manufacturing something using CE marked components then [your product has to be CE marked](http://www.ce-marking.com/what-is-a-manufacturer.html). You can't just rely on all your components being CE marked because your product as a whole might not comply. Selling the components as a kit also does not avoid the need to CE mark your product.

A CE mark is simply a declaration that your product conforms to all the relevant EU regulations. [How you demonstrate this](http://www.ce-marking.org/how-obtain.html) depends on the product. You may be able to demonstrate "minimal risk" if, for instance, you use a CE marked transformer that outputs 12 volts to the rest of the lighting, and there is no possibility of anything getting hot enough to burn someone. In that case you can just record your reasoning and stick the CE mark on the product.

If you are merely selling in the UK then I don't think you don't need CE marking. However as a practical matter you should still consider getting it because it will help avoid possible negligence claims and/or prosecution if something bad happens due to one of your products. You might also want to consider legal insurance against such an eventuality.